# What are the pros and cons of these two(a common data structure to represent different types of data)?

Tags: c

If I want to use a common data structure to represent different types of data. I can use two ways.

```
struct base {
    int type;//can be GCObject
};

struct string {
    struct base info;
    int len;
    char *data;
};

struct number {
    struct base info;
    double num;
};
```

or

```
struct string {
    int len;
    char *data;
};

struct number{
    double num;
};

struct value {
    int type;
    union {
        string str;
        number num;
    } value;
};
```

What are the pros and cons of these two?

Just like I want to create a new language. I want to use a common struct data structure represent different types of data. Just like Lua's table. In the first proposal, base like a base class, string and number like a sub class.

Comment: `char *data[O] ;` --> con: invalid C code.

Comment: You probably ant `char *data[0];` -> `char *data[;`

Comment: And your n`struct base` is odd because it has only one data member. A struct with onlyone data member is pretty useless. Instead of `struct base` you could use `int` directly.

Comment: Without a good description of how the data structures will be used (and perhaps some code examples), it's not possible to answer this question. Further, the posted code isn't valid C code.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming (you didn't tell us) that you want to use both types interchangeable with some generic function, I would use the second definition with the union. You can pass around objects and pointers to `struct value` and decide on the `type` field what to access in the `value` field.

Your first proposal needs casting everywhere, and it is not safe against the next developer inserting fields before `type`. This person can be your future self.